# MYSQL pagination performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following sample MYSQL table:

```
id | count_likes
-----------
1  |  30
2  |  95
3  |  60
4  |  60
5  |  22
```

I want to order the table by column `count_likes` descending and display 5 rows at a time (this is a sample table so assume thousands of rows).

To achieve this I run the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY count_likes DESC, id DESC LIMIT 5
```

I want to give the option for users to load more rows like loading facebook comments for example (5 rows at a time).

To achieve this I run the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN(values already loaded)
ORDER BY count_likes DESC, id DESC LIMIT 5
```

This could work well for few pages but I think it's not recommended to have like hundred values in the `WHERE NOT IN` clause.

If I make the command like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE count_likes < 'the last displayed count number'
```

I could miss some rows which have the same count like the last loaded row.

If I make the command like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE count_likes <= 'the last displayed count number'
```

I could get duplicate values that are already loaded.

If I make the command like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY count_likes DESC LIMIT offset,5
```

I may get disorganized or duplicate rows as the `count_likes` for any row may increase or decrease while other users are manipulating the same page.

What is the best way to load more rows in my case above?

The most accurate one would be the `WHERE NOT IN` but I don't know if it causes performance issues on large number of members like hundred or even thousand.

Comment: Pagination is a widely discussed topic. Do you really want to rehearse it all again here?

Comment: No just what to do in my case. That's all I need :)